# Getting user added row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following DataGridView which is bound to a List:

```
List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null);
dataGridView1.UserAddedRow += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_UserAddedRow);

void dataGridViewMilight_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e) {

    // e.Row.DataBoundItem is always null?
}
```

How can I get the Object that was added to my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a DataGridView bound to a DataView. I wanted to give default values to hidden (unbound) fields when a DataRow was created but there was never any bound item.

I fixed the problem by handling the ListChanged event raised by the DataView (when  the ListChangedType property of the event equals to ItemAdded). You can handle the same event if you use a BindingList instead of a list, or any class implementing IBindingList.

Comment: I'd recommend using the [DefaultValuesNeeded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/specify-default-values-for-new-rows-in-the-datagrid) event to pre-populate some fields in a new user added row.

Comment: As far as I understand DefaultValuesNeeded is a good choice if you needed to provide values **that are bound to your grid**. If you also need to provide values for fields not bound a DataGridViewColumn you’ll need either to handle the source’s ListChanged event or to use hidden columns. Anyway your solution seems simpler for most use cases since it doesn't depends on the nature of the data source.

Answer (score -2):

The **Row** property of the provided **DataGridViewRowEventArgs** instance is the newly created row.

```
void dataGridViewMilight_UserAddedRow(object sender,
                                      DataGridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    DataGridViewRow newRow = e.Row;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to access the Object in list which that row corresponds to. To do this I tried e.Row.DataBoundItem, but it seems to always be null.

Comment: Oh, that I am not sure about. Try setting a break point on the source list for when a new object is added. Then run your code and see at what point the object instance is actually added to the source control and look at the stack to see when it occurs in the grid. That might give a clue.