# Inline adding row with BindingSource and Validate data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

After searching for a solution for some time, I rely on you because I can't get out of it.

I have a DataGridView with the data source linked to a BindingSource.
The BindingSource data source is a DataTable object.

The dgv has the "Allow insertion" option enabled and my goal is to allow the user to enter by adding with submission on the last line and validate the data with RowValidate method.
I want to check, before insert, that a column is filled with data.

To allow insertion, I use the AddingNew method of BindingSource like this:

```
        private void bsAnalisi_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dgvRow;
            ANALISI_DL AnalisiDL;
            //
                if (dgvAnalisi.CurrentRow != null)
                {
                    dgvRow = dgvAnalisi.CurrentRow;

                    //if ((Convert.ToInt32(dgvRow.Cells["ID"].Value) == 0))
                    if (dgvRow.Cells["ID"].Value == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        Analisi = new ANALISI();
                        AnalisiDL = new ANALISI_DL();

                        Analisi.LOTTO = dgvRow.Cells["LOTTO"].Value == null ? string.Empty : dgvRow.Cells["LOTTO"].Value.ToString();
                       //some other columns    

                        //I call a stored procedure
                        Analisi.ID = AnalisiDL.InsertAnalisi(Analisi);

                        //refresh the bindingsource
                        dgvDataBindings();

                    }               

        }
```

To refresh I use this method :

```
        private void dgvDataBindings()
        {
            ANALISI_DL AnalisiDL;
            //    

            AnalisiDL = new ANALISI_DL();

            bsAnalisi.DataSource = AnalisiDL.GetAllAnalisi();
        }
```

The insert operation goes well but I view a blank row at the bottom of the grid(under the new row).

In addition when I try to refresh the grid with the dgvDataBindings method (by a button) I get the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation failed. The cell value cannot be committed or uncommitted.'

Is it the correct way to insert a new row ?
I also tried with the CellEndEdit method of the DataGridView but the event fire before of RowValidation event.

****EDIT****
These are the methods i use to get and insert data and validate  :

```
        public DataTable GetAllAnalisi()
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa;
            DataTable dt;
            //
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ANALISI ORDER BY ID", conn);
                dt = new DataTable();
                sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            }
            return dt;
        }


public int InsertAnalisi(ANALISI pAnalisi)
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            string SQLString;
            int result;
            //

            SQLString = "dbo.SP_INSERT_ANALISI";

            using (conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOTTO", pAnalisi.LOTTO);
                    
                    //some other columns

                    var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
                    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    result = Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void dgvAnalisi_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row;

            row = dgvAnalisi.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            if (row.IsNewRow) { return; }

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.OwningColumn.Name == "FK_SEDE")
                {
                    if (cell.Value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        row.ErrorText = "Error";
                        e.Cancel = true;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to call `dgvDataBindings();`  Your add new code shouldn't be calling `AnalisiDL = new ANALISI_DL();` either.

Comment: If I don't call `dgvDataBindings();` the row seems not inserted because I can't see the Identity value. Is there a method to call after the AddingNew to refresh data?

Comment: A DataTable object should be automatically updating the source.  We probably have to see this code: `Analisi.ID = AnalisiDL.InsertAnalisi(Analisi);` and your original binding code.

Comment: I edit the post with the definition of the method I use to insert and get data

Comment: It is difficult to understand what issues you are having. As noted in the comments, if the grid is using a `BindingSource` and the `BindingSource` uses a `DataTable`, then, when you “add” the row to the grid, then this should automatically be reflected in the underlying `DataTable`. It is unnecessary to “add” the row to the binding source since this is done for you automatically.

Comment: Also, you state that, you want to _”validate the data with RowValidate method”_ … however, I do not see this method in the posted code, in addition, I do not see any “validation” done anywhere in the posted code. It appears that the code is “checking” the “Lotto” value in the grid in the `AddingNew` method, however, it is simply checking for an “empty” cell. So, it is unclear what data you are wanting to “validate.” Can you clarify what data (cells) you want to validate AND what you want to do IF the data is not valid.

Comment: @JohnG I don't understand when I should call the method to save the data to the database.
The AddingNew is not the correct way ?
I also edit the post with the validatingrow method.
My goal is check if a columns has value before save it to database.

Comment: Again… What do you want to do IF the value in the cell is NOT valid? … Take a look at this answer I recently supplied. It may help. If  you have issues, post what you have tried and let me know. [Getting values from user added row in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505932/getting-values-from-user-added-row-in-datagridview/64510804#64510804)

Comment: @JohnG thank you! The post that you shared is exactly whatI have to do.